# XSL transform childnodes located in paragraph text

Tags: xslt

Suppose I have the following xml, what xsl do I need to transform the `note` tags inside the `p` tags to a `sup` tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<root>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent<note>1</note> vel nisi non sapien venenatis vehicula. Nunc et dignissim ligula. Praesent aliquet nisl eget quam sollicitudin a faucibus eros dapibus. Aliquam cursus elit at tortor lacinia congue. Donec sit amet felis risus, a mollis ante. Integer sit amet massa sed metus semper cursus id id enim. Vestibulum felis nunc, pellentesque non lobortis et, porttitor eu libero. Curabitur eget nulla quam. Etiam erat arcu, vulputate sed volutpat consequat, adipiscing et tortor. Quisque imperdiet laoreet fermentum. Mauris ac felis vel lectus semper posuere. Etiam luctus augue et odio suscipit varius. Curabitur tincidunt purus quis tellus pretium imperdiet. In rhoncus rutrum orci, sed venenatis sem volutpat non. Curabitur tincidunt lacinia sem at luctus. Donec et diam eu massa interdum dapibus a et elit. Donec malesuada urna et nunc volutpat gravida.</p>
<p>Donec varius placerat venenatis. In neque sem, sollicitudin sed eleifend et, tristique eu turpis. Donec quis nisi lectus. Nullam gravida vestibulum arcu non aliquet. Nullam ut felis metus. Proin mollis tellus eu eros iaculis eget tristique leo fermentum. Pellentesque nec lorem vitae nibh eleifend euismod. Pellentesque nec gravida neque. Praesent mattis mi sed nisi sodales porta. Morbi risus mauris, convallis at condimentum a, interdum nec purus. Cras vulputate faucibus tempor. Aliquam eu dolor sed eros malesuada pharetra vitae vitae est. Suspendisse lacinia urna vitae mi bibendum quis<note>2</note> scelerisque augue tristique. Aenean at arcu tellus, eu placerat enim. Cras ultrices iaculis augue vitae pharetra. Praesent suscipit blandit scelerisque. Mauris et molestie purus. Vivamus volutpat enim sem, eget scelerisque turpis. Praesent viverra lectus in ipsum tristique blandit. Donec lobortis molestie purus, at feugiat leo rhoncus eget.</p>
<p>Vivamus eget convallis massa. Etiam convallis gravida tincidunt. Suspendisse tincidunt dignissim accumsan. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam commodo placerat egestas. Donec convallis sodales volutpat. Quisque dapibus lobortis augue sit amet rhoncus. Nulla sed sem nisl, in feugiat orci. Quisque vehicula iaculis nisi ut auctor. Integer molestie nisl eget diam pharetra interdum. Mauris aliquet, libero vel congue egestas, velit est pretium leo, luctus commodo risus diam sed odio. Nullam pretium blandit ligula, quis commodo massa rhoncus eu. Nunc in hendrerit mi. Cras quis orci ut metus lacinia eleifend id eu nisi. Nunc id varius diam. Aliquam eu porta velit. Curabitur eget<note>3</note> odio neque, et aliquam nisi.</p>
<notes>
<note><nr>1</nr>Suspendisse tincidunt dignissim accumsan</note>
<note><nr>2</nr>Nunc et dignissim ligula</note>
<note><nr>3</nr>eget convallis massa</note>
</notes>
</root>
```

and xsl stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/root/*">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name() = 'p'">
          <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="name() = 'notes'">
          <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a very short and in the XSLT spirit (push style) solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to change the `p/note` to a `sup` is an identity template (search SO, there's a lot of answers to this) and another template to match `p/note` (see below).

But I would go for something like this since your stylesheet produces some what strange output, but it's not necessarily what you wanted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p/note">
    <sup>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </sup>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="notes">
    <ol>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="nr" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ol>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="notes/note">
    <li>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="nr"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will transform your data into a HTML document with `p/note` to a `sup` and `notes/note` to an ordered list.

Comment: I wonder where the first reply went??? anyway this transforms the note inside the p tag to sup tags. There is howerever an error in the notes/note part: "Expected token 'eof' found 'NAME'. node() -->except <--nr
"

Comment: I assumed you used XSLT 2.0 since you're stylesheet says so. But it seems you're processing a 2.0 stylesheet with a XSLT 1.0 compliant processor. However, I've rewritten the parts above to work with XSLT 1.0 (since 2.0 isn't really needed). Please try my code again!

Comment: That works fine, just fine. Thanks a lot. One more questions, what does the 'node() | @*'do?

Comment: It matches all nodes and attributes in the document, I suggest you read about [identity templates](http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity), there's a lot both here at SO about it. Also, if my solution works, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I have the following xml, what
>   xsl do I need to transform the `note`
>   tags inside the `p` tags to a `sup`
>   tag?

**This transformation**: **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** plus override for `p/note`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p/note">
  <sup><xsl:apply-templates/></sup>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent
        <note>1</note> vel nisi non sapien venenatis vehicula. Nunc et dignissim ligula. Praesent aliquet nisl eget quam sollicitudin a faucibus eros dapibus. Aliquam cursus elit at tortor lacinia congue. Donec sit amet felis risus, a mollis ante. Integer sit amet massa sed metus semper cursus id id enim. Vestibulum felis nunc, pellentesque non lobortis et, porttitor eu libero. Curabitur eget nulla quam. Etiam erat arcu, vulputate sed volutpat consequat, adipiscing et tortor. Quisque imperdiet laoreet fermentum. Mauris ac felis vel lectus semper posuere. Etiam luctus augue et odio suscipit varius. Curabitur tincidunt purus quis tellus pretium imperdiet. In rhoncus rutrum orci, sed venenatis sem volutpat non. Curabitur tincidunt lacinia sem at luctus. Donec et diam eu massa interdum dapibus a et elit. Donec malesuada urna et nunc volutpat gravida.
    </p>
    <p>Donec varius placerat venenatis. In neque sem, sollicitudin sed eleifend et, tristique eu turpis. Donec quis nisi lectus. Nullam gravida vestibulum arcu non aliquet. Nullam ut felis metus. Proin mollis tellus eu eros iaculis eget tristique leo fermentum. Pellentesque nec lorem vitae nibh eleifend euismod. Pellentesque nec gravida neque. Praesent mattis mi sed nisi sodales porta. Morbi risus mauris, convallis at condimentum a, interdum nec purus. Cras vulputate faucibus tempor. Aliquam eu dolor sed eros malesuada pharetra vitae vitae est. Suspendisse lacinia urna vitae mi bibendum quis
        <note>2</note> scelerisque augue tristique. Aenean at arcu tellus, eu placerat enim. Cras ultrices iaculis augue vitae pharetra. Praesent suscipit blandit scelerisque. Mauris et molestie purus. Vivamus volutpat enim sem, eget scelerisque turpis. Praesent viverra lectus in ipsum tristique blandit. Donec lobortis molestie purus, at feugiat leo rhoncus eget.
    </p>
    <p>Vivamus eget convallis massa. Etiam convallis gravida tincidunt. Suspendisse tincidunt dignissim accumsan. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam commodo placerat egestas. Donec convallis sodales volutpat. Quisque dapibus lobortis augue sit amet rhoncus. Nulla sed sem nisl, in feugiat orci. Quisque vehicula iaculis nisi ut auctor. Integer molestie nisl eget diam pharetra interdum. Mauris aliquet, libero vel congue egestas, velit est pretium leo, luctus commodo risus diam sed odio. Nullam pretium blandit ligula, quis commodo massa rhoncus eu. Nunc in hendrerit mi. Cras quis orci ut metus lacinia eleifend id eu nisi. Nunc id varius diam. Aliquam eu porta velit. Curabitur eget
        <note>3</note> odio neque, et aliquam nisi.
    </p>
    <notes>
        <note>
            <nr>1</nr>Suspendisse tincidunt dignissim accumsan
        </note>
        <note>
            <nr>2</nr>Nunc et dignissim ligula
        </note>
        <note>
            <nr>3</nr>eget convallis massa
        </note>
    </notes>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent
        <sup>1</sup> vel nisi non sapien venenatis vehicula. Nunc et dignissim ligula. Praesent aliquet nisl eget quam sollicitudin a faucibus eros dapibus. Aliquam cursus elit at tortor lacinia congue. Donec sit amet felis risus, a mollis ante. Integer sit amet massa sed metus semper cursus id id enim. Vestibulum felis nunc, pellentesque non lobortis et, porttitor eu libero. Curabitur eget nulla quam. Etiam erat arcu, vulputate sed volutpat consequat, adipiscing et tortor. Quisque imperdiet laoreet fermentum. Mauris ac felis vel lectus semper posuere. Etiam luctus augue et odio suscipit varius. Curabitur tincidunt purus quis tellus pretium imperdiet. In rhoncus rutrum orci, sed venenatis sem volutpat non. Curabitur tincidunt lacinia sem at luctus. Donec et diam eu massa interdum dapibus a et elit. Donec malesuada urna et nunc volutpat gravida.
    </p>
   <p>Donec varius placerat venenatis. In neque sem, sollicitudin sed eleifend et, tristique eu turpis. Donec quis nisi lectus. Nullam gravida vestibulum arcu non aliquet. Nullam ut felis metus. Proin mollis tellus eu eros iaculis eget tristique leo fermentum. Pellentesque nec lorem vitae nibh eleifend euismod. Pellentesque nec gravida neque. Praesent mattis mi sed nisi sodales porta. Morbi risus mauris, convallis at condimentum a, interdum nec purus. Cras vulputate faucibus tempor. Aliquam eu dolor sed eros malesuada pharetra vitae vitae est. Suspendisse lacinia urna vitae mi bibendum quis
        <sup>2</sup> scelerisque augue tristique. Aenean at arcu tellus, eu placerat enim. Cras ultrices iaculis augue vitae pharetra. Praesent suscipit blandit scelerisque. Mauris et molestie purus. Vivamus volutpat enim sem, eget scelerisque turpis. Praesent viverra lectus in ipsum tristique blandit. Donec lobortis molestie purus, at feugiat leo rhoncus eget.
    </p>
   <p>Vivamus eget convallis massa. Etiam convallis gravida tincidunt. Suspendisse tincidunt dignissim accumsan. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam commodo placerat egestas. Donec convallis sodales volutpat. Quisque dapibus lobortis augue sit amet rhoncus. Nulla sed sem nisl, in feugiat orci. Quisque vehicula iaculis nisi ut auctor. Integer molestie nisl eget diam pharetra interdum. Mauris aliquet, libero vel congue egestas, velit est pretium leo, luctus commodo risus diam sed odio. Nullam pretium blandit ligula, quis commodo massa rhoncus eu. Nunc in hendrerit mi. Cras quis orci ut metus lacinia eleifend id eu nisi. Nunc id varius diam. Aliquam eu porta velit. Curabitur eget
        <sup>3</sup> odio neque, et aliquam nisi.
    </p>
   <notes>
      <note>
         <nr>1</nr>Suspendisse tincidunt dignissim accumsan
        </note>
      <note>
         <nr>2</nr>Nunc et dignissim ligula
        </note>
      <note>
         <nr>3</nr>eget convallis massa
        </note>
   </notes>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p/note" name="sup">
        <sup>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </sup>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="notes/note">
        <p>
            <xsl:call-template name="sup"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nr">
        <b style="margin-right:5px">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </b>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent<sup>1</sup> vel nisi non sapien venenatis vehicula. Nunc et dignissim ligula. Praesent aliquet nisl eget quam sollicitudin a faucibus eros dapibus. Aliquam cursus elit at tortor lacinia congue. Donec sit amet felis risus, a mollis ante. Integer sit amet massa sed metus semper cursus id id enim. Vestibulum felis nunc, pellentesque non lobortis et, porttitor eu libero. Curabitur eget nulla quam. Etiam erat arcu, vulputate sed volutpat consequat, adipiscing et tortor. Quisque imperdiet laoreet fermentum. Mauris ac felis vel lectus semper posuere. Etiam luctus augue et odio suscipit varius. Curabitur tincidunt purus quis tellus pretium imperdiet. In rhoncus rutrum orci, sed venenatis sem volutpat non. Curabitur tincidunt lacinia sem at luctus. Donec et diam eu massa interdum dapibus a et elit. Donec malesuada urna et nunc volutpat gravida.</p>
<p>Donec varius placerat venenatis. In neque sem, sollicitudin sed eleifend et, tristique eu turpis. Donec quis nisi lectus. Nullam gravida vestibulum arcu non aliquet. Nullam ut felis metus. Proin mollis tellus eu eros iaculis eget tristique leo fermentum. Pellentesque nec lorem vitae nibh eleifend euismod. Pellentesque nec gravida neque. Praesent mattis mi sed nisi sodales porta. Morbi risus mauris, convallis at condimentum a, interdum nec purus. Cras vulputate faucibus tempor. Aliquam eu dolor sed eros malesuada pharetra vitae vitae est. Suspendisse lacinia urna vitae mi bibendum quis<sup>2</sup> scelerisque augue tristique. Aenean at arcu tellus, eu placerat enim. Cras ultrices iaculis augue vitae pharetra. Praesent suscipit blandit scelerisque. Mauris et molestie purus. Vivamus volutpat enim sem, eget scelerisque turpis. Praesent viverra lectus in ipsum tristique blandit. Donec lobortis molestie purus, at feugiat leo rhoncus eget.</p>
<p>Vivamus eget convallis massa. Etiam convallis gravida tincidunt. Suspendisse tincidunt dignissim accumsan. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam commodo placerat egestas. Donec convallis sodales volutpat. Quisque dapibus lobortis augue sit amet rhoncus. Nulla sed sem nisl, in feugiat orci. Quisque vehicula iaculis nisi ut auctor. Integer molestie nisl eget diam pharetra interdum. Mauris aliquet, libero vel congue egestas, velit est pretium leo, luctus commodo risus diam sed odio. Nullam pretium blandit ligula, quis commodo massa rhoncus eu. Nunc in hendrerit mi. Cras quis orci ut metus lacinia eleifend id eu nisi. Nunc id varius diam. Aliquam eu porta velit. Curabitur eget<sup>3</sup> odio neque, et aliquam nisi.</p>
<p><sup><b style="margin-right:5px">1</b>Suspendisse tincidunt dignissim accumsan</sup></p>
<p><sup><b style="margin-right:5px">2</b>Nunc et dignissim ligula</sup></p>
<p><sup><b style="margin-right:5px">3</b>eget convallis massa</sup></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Render:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent<sup>1</sup> vel nisi non sapien venenatis vehicula. Nunc et dignissim ligula. Praesent aliquet nisl eget quam sollicitudin a faucibus eros dapibus. Aliquam cursus elit at tortor lacinia congue. Donec sit amet felis risus, a mollis ante. Integer sit amet massa sed metus semper cursus id id enim. Vestibulum felis nunc, pellentesque non lobortis et, porttitor eu libero. Curabitur eget nulla quam. Etiam erat arcu, vulputate sed volutpat consequat, adipiscing et tortor. Quisque imperdiet laoreet fermentum. Mauris ac felis vel lectus semper posuere. Etiam luctus augue et odio suscipit varius. Curabitur tincidunt purus quis tellus pretium imperdiet. In rhoncus rutrum orci, sed venenatis sem volutpat non. Curabitur tincidunt lacinia sem at luctus. Donec et diam eu massa interdum dapibus a et elit. Donec malesuada urna et nunc volutpat gravida.

Donec varius placerat venenatis. In neque sem, sollicitudin sed eleifend et, tristique eu turpis. Donec quis nisi lectus. Nullam gravida vestibulum arcu non aliquet. Nullam ut felis metus. Proin mollis tellus eu eros iaculis eget tristique leo fermentum. Pellentesque nec lorem vitae nibh eleifend euismod. Pellentesque nec gravida neque. Praesent mattis mi sed nisi sodales porta. Morbi risus mauris, convallis at condimentum a, interdum nec purus. Cras vulputate faucibus tempor. Aliquam eu dolor sed eros malesuada pharetra vitae vitae est. Suspendisse lacinia urna vitae mi bibendum quis<sup>2</sup> scelerisque augue tristique. Aenean at arcu tellus, eu placerat enim. Cras ultrices iaculis augue vitae pharetra. Praesent suscipit blandit scelerisque. Mauris et molestie purus. Vivamus volutpat enim sem, eget scelerisque turpis. Praesent viverra lectus in ipsum tristique blandit. Donec lobortis molestie purus, at feugiat leo rhoncus eget.

Vivamus eget convallis massa. Etiam convallis gravida tincidunt. Suspendisse tincidunt dignissim accumsan. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam commodo placerat egestas. Donec convallis sodales volutpat. Quisque dapibus lobortis augue sit amet rhoncus. Nulla sed sem nisl, in feugiat orci. Quisque vehicula iaculis nisi ut auctor. Integer molestie nisl eget diam pharetra interdum. Mauris aliquet, libero vel congue egestas, velit est pretium leo, luctus commodo risus diam sed odio. Nullam pretium blandit ligula, quis commodo massa rhoncus eu. Nunc in hendrerit mi. Cras quis orci ut metus lacinia eleifend id eu nisi. Nunc id varius diam. Aliquam eu porta velit. Curabitur eget<sup>3</sup> odio neque, et aliquam nisi.

<sup>1Suspendisse tincidunt dignissim accumsan</sup>

<sup>2Nunc et dignissim ligula</sup>

<sup>3eget convallis massa</sup>

Also, an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p|notes/note">
        <p>
            <xsl:next-match/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="note" name="sup">
        <sup>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </sup>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nr">
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </b>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: After making the change, I didn't think that it looked right. Guess that's why...Sorry about that.